# 2 dimensional box in quantum physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

Why exactly do we consider the potential energy zero inside the 2D box and infinity behind the wall? Why is the potential energy component of the Schrodinger's wave equation neglected? Could anyone just tell me the intuition behind considering a 2d box and neglecting potential energy.

Comment: The infinite potential is not neglected. It has consequences. How do you think the wavefunction behaves in regions with infinite potential?

Comment: I meant inside the box

Comment: The bottom level of the [infinite potential well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box) is just a convention.  The set of solutions with one convention is isomorphic to the set of solutions with another convention.

Answer (score 0):

We're not neglecting the potential nor do we necessarily consider it to be $0$: it's enough to consider it to be constant, say $V_0$.  The Schrodinger equation then reads
\begin{align}
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi(x)
+V_0\psi(x)&=E\psi(x) \\
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi(x)
&=(E-V_0)\psi(x) \tag{1}
\end{align}
which is the same as solving for $\bar E=E-V_0$ with $0$ potential.

Intuitively, the potential energy is always defined in relation to some reference;  this reference here is the height of the wall, which is infinite.  Thus, it doesn't matter if $V_0$ is $5$eV or $10$eV since the difference between the reference and $V_0$ is always infinite.  What $V_0$ does is shift the values energy up by that much.  Solving Eq.(1) will give
$$
E_n-V_0 = \frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{2mL^2}\quad
\Rightarrow\quad 
E_n=V_0+ \frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{2mL^2}
$$
but it does not otherwise affect the solutions, which are still
$$
\psi_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin(k_nx)
$$
with $E_n=V_0+\frac{\hbar^2 k_n^2}{2m}$.  This is because the boundary conditions at $x=0$ and $x=L$ are unchanged by adding the constant potential $V_0$ since the walls are already infinitely high.